# Why can't to work nodejs script in react frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, promise, async-await

There is a tcp sensor query that works well in node js script and backend.
I tried to use it directly in react frontend but it doesn't work, but similar web query with fetch working properly.
Can i to use any nodejs code in frontend?

I tried several variations and now is no error message but it doesn't work.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./app.css";

const command = new Buffer.from([0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00]); // Poll Command

function tcpRead(port, IP, timeout, command) {
  console.log(command);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const net = require("net");
    const client = new net.Socket();
    client.setTimeout(timeout);
    // client.setEncoding('utf8');
    client.connect(port, IP, () => {
      client.write(command);
    });
    client.on("data", (data, callback) => {
      resolve(data);
      client.destroy();
    });
    client.on("error", err => {
      reject("error");
    });
    client.on("timeout", () => {
      reject("timeuot");
      client.destroy();
    });
  });
}

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch("https://api.ipify.org?format=json");
    const { ip } = await res.json();
    await this.setStateAsync({ ipAddress: ip });

    const { sensor } = await tcpRead(7777, "137.76.113.55", 1000, command);
    await this.setStateAsync({ sensorData: sensor });
  }

  setStateAsync(state) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.setState(state, resolve);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>My IP is {this.state.ipAddress || "Unknown"}</h2>
        <h2>Sensor Data is {this.state.sensorData || "Unknown"}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Can i to use any nodejs code in frontend?"* ... only if it is supported in front end and is intended to be used there

Comment: Above comment is on point. To support that look at this line `const command = new Buffer.from([0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00]);` Here `Buffer` is node specific/feature and would not work on a browser ie: frontend.

Comment: Well, a browser doesn't have `require('net')` and allows you to do arbitrary TCP connections. Unless you are running this in electron or something else that exposes such an API, it just won't work.

Comment: I got answer, so
It is impossible that the 'net' and 'file' will ever be passed to the client page until such an API is written..
One solution is to run the (net and file) functions on the server side and browser data exchange with AJAX.

Thank You,
Zsolt